# An application of the uniform boundedness principle

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Can someone provide me with a sketch of proof / hint for this exercise:

Let K $\subset$ $L^1([0,1]\,,\, \mu)$ be a closed linear subspace. If $\forall$ $f \in K$, $\exists \, p > 1$ such that $f \in L^p$, then $\exists \, p > 0 \Rightarrow\, K \subset L^p$.

I understand that the uniform boundedness principle should be applied here, but I have no clue how. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: See Problem 8 [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.math.gatech.edu%2F~bwick6%2Fteaching%2Fmath6338%2Fmath6338_exam1.pdf&ei=ZMFZVbTsCofBtQXM24CYBg&usg=AFQjCNE-N1AzYgd37qzO5C7OiapRiIi-zg&bvm=bv.93564037,d.b2w&cad=rja) for a solution using Baire category..